# duplicate compile flag in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp

I am trying to use cmake to link my project.

I need to find a package `mypack`, it will give me `mypack_definitions`, `mypack_flags`, `mypack_include_dirs` , and `mypack_libraries`. Here `mypack_flags` contains relevant flags for linking mypack. I will add `mypack_flags` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Please see the CMakeLists.txt below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(QMCLIB C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")

find_package(mypack REQUIRED)

add_executable(QMC codeA.cpp codeB.cpp )
add_definitions(${mypack_definitions})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${mypack_flags}")
target_link_libraries(QMC ${mypack_libraries})
target_include_directories(QMC PUBLIC ${mypack_include_dirs})
```

However depend on the systems, `mypack_flags` might or not contain `-fopenmp`, when it contains `-fopenmp`, my `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` will have two `-fopenmp`. I can not remove `-fopenmp` in

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")
```

If I remove it, when `mypack_flags` does not contains `-fopenmp`, then I will have no `-fopenmp` in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Is there a way to force cmake only use one `-fopenmp`? Or is it okay to have two `-fopenmp`? Thank you for your suggestion.

======================================================================

Thanks to Robert Prévost, here is a general function to remove duplicate substrings:

```
function(removeDuplicateSubstring stringIn stringOut)
    separate_arguments(stringIn)
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES stringIn)
    string(REPLACE ";" " " stringIn "${stringIn}")
    set(${stringOut} "${stringIn}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

We can call this function by:

```
 removeDuplicateSubstring(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the `list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES <list>)` solution, I would advice to avoid using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` nor `add_*` commands, and prefer `target_*` commands instead:

- [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html);
- [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html);
- [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html).

Your cmake file may become something like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(QMCLIB C CXX)

function(removeDuplicateSubstring stringIn stringOut)
    separate_arguments(stringIn)
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES stringIn)
    string(REPLACE ";" " " stringIn "${stringIn}")
    set(${stringOut} "${stringIn}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

find_package(mypack REQUIRED)

set(mycompile_options -fopenmp ${mypack_flags})

removeDuplicateSubstring(${mycompile_options} mycompile_options)

add_executable(QMC codeA.cpp codeB.cpp )
target_compile_definitions(QMC PUBLIC ${mypack_definitions})
target_compile_options(QMC PUBLIC ${mycompile_options})
target_compile_features(QMC PUBLIC cxx_constexpr)
target_include_directories(QMC PUBLIC ${mypack_include_dirs})
target_link_libraries(QMC ${mypack_libraries})
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to make CMake only include one `-fopenmp`.  `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is a string that you can search for substrings.  You can conditionally add `-fopenmp` based upon whether you find it already in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.  Assuming that you were careful not to already add it twice, then you can use the following check to see if you need to add it.

```
# find "-fopenmp"
string(FIND ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-fopenmp" FLAG_INDEX)
# check if we found it
if (FLAG_INDEX GREATER 0)
   message(STATUS "WE'VE GOT AT LEAST ONE!")
else()
   message(STATUS "WE'VE GOT NONE; ADD IT!")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")
endif()
```

Just to be safe you could remove all instances of `-fopenmp` and then add it back in.

```
# remove all occurrences of "-fopenmp"
string(REPLACE "-fopenmp" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I write a function followed by your idea. It removes duplicated substrings in a string.